# What happens when I call QWidget->close()

Tags: qt, qt4, qwidget

I would like to know what happens when I call QWidget-close()  I called it after a setup function I coded and this disabled some of my slots to get called.

before(creates odd behavior):
            `pGrpCfg->setupGrpConfig();

            pGrpCfg->close();

            pGrpCfg->show();`

after(ok):
            `pGrpCfg->close();

            pGrpCfg->setupGrpConfig();

            pGrpCfg->show();`

This is my function.  The only thing I suspect could have an impact on it is the Signal connections(I would like to add that these connections start in the constructor where I use QSignalMapper):

void grpConfig::setupGrpConfig(){ 
    disconnect(signalMapper, SIGNAL(mapped(int)), this, SIGNAL(txGrpComboBoxCurItemChanged(const int)));
    disconnect(this, SIGNAL(txGrpComboBoxCurItemChanged(const int)),this,SLOT(updateTxFailOrderLayouts(int)));

```
myFPS->getData(REQUEST_SYSTEM_CONFIGURATION);
int numTxChains=myFPS->SystemData.NumberOfTransmitterChainsInSystem;
grpList.clear();
grpList.append("Select group");
for(int i=0;i<MAX_GROUPS;i++){
    myFPS->getData(REQUEST_GROUP_INFORMATION,i);
    grpCfgEleList.at(i)->ui.leGrpName->setText(myFPS->GroupData.Group[i].Name);
    grpList.append(myFPS->GroupData.Group[i].Name);
}
for(int i=0;i<numTxChains;i++){

    myFPS->getData(REQUEST_TX_CONFIGURATION,i);
    txNameList.at(i)->setVisible(true);
    txNameList.at(i)->setText(myFPS->TransmitterConfigurationData[i].Name);
    txGrpCBlist.at(i)->setVisible(true);
    txGrpCBlist.at(i)->clear();
    txGrpCBlist.at(i)->addItems(grpList);
    txGrpCBlist.at(i)->setCurrentIndex(myFPS->TransmitterConfigurationData[i].Group+INDEX_OFFSET);

}
for(int i=numTxChains;i<MAX_NUMBER_OF_TRANSMITTERS;i++){
    txNameList.at(i)->setVisible(false);
    txGrpCBlist.at(i)->setVisible(false);
}

for(int i=0;i<MAX_GROUPS;i++){
    updateGrpFailover(i, STAY,-1);
}
//need to wait till setup is complete to activate these signals (populating comboboxes overwrote UDP structs with false data)
connect(signalMapper, SIGNAL(mapped(int)), this, SIGNAL(txGrpComboBoxCurItemChanged(const int)));
connect(this, SIGNAL(txGrpComboBoxCurItemChanged(const int)),this,SLOT(updateTxFailOrderLayouts(int)));
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: when I called QWidget->Close(), this destroys my signal connection.  The signal connections are made in setupGrpConfig so to call close after setupGrpConfig voided the signal connections.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `QWidget::hide()` instead of `close()`.

Answer (score 1):

http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qwidget.html#close

It tells you exactly what it does.  What type is `pGrpCfg`?
That will tell you what the reimplemented version of the function is doing.

Comment: Why the downvote?  The documentation says what the function does, and you are not providing enough information to help answer more about it.

Comment: well it doesnt say everything because I read that, and I even read the source code and there is something else happening that is not being told because the signal I connect in the function setupGrpConfig gets voided just because of the order it gets called from..